# Changing column in Laravel migration causes exception: Changing columns for table requires Doctrine DBAL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

I'm trying to change the max length of one of my columns in table `reserves` in one migration. The code looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::table('reserves', function($table){
        $table->string("mobile", 11)->change();
    });
}
```

But when running the migration via artisan, it throws an exception and says:

> [RuntimeException] Changing columns for table "reserves" requires
>   Doctrine DBAL; install "doctrine/dbal".

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The problem was solved by executing the following command on the root directory of the framework:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: Why this is not installed by default?

Comment: @NicuVlad It's not installed by default because the designers wanted to keep it out of the framework because they see these as more of an edge case. You can always just pull it in if you need it so they opted to keep it out of the core framework to avoid bloat. I can't say I agree, I use it all the time, but that's the reason.

Comment: Note that you may encounter the "Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found" error. Therefore, add the phrase " doctrine / dbal ":" ^ 2.0 ", to the composer file.

Comment: Would be probably helpful to cite the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns): `Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file.`

Answer (score 3):

add to composer.json

```
"require": {
        ...
        "doctrine/dbal": "*"
    },
```

run "composer update" command

Answer (score 0):

or if you can't install the library then:

```
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `reserves` MODIFY mobile varchar(11)');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to update the column name

**Option 1:** Install `doctrine/dbal` package via composer

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Note: If you don't want to install a package then use go to `option 2`.

**Option 2:** use `DB::statement` with `alter` query to update a column

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE reserves MODIFY COLUMN mobile VARCHAR(11)');
```